# Ref is null in React Native renderer.create() call in unit test which is failing my test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am using

```
"react": "^16.4.0",
"jest": "^22.4.4",
```

Then in my component I am using react native dropdown alert

```
 import DropdownAlert from 'react-native-dropdownalert';
```

Inside of my render function I have placed it at the very bottom

```
  <DropdownAlert
      ref={this.dropdownRef}
    />
```

And then in my constructor I add the following ref

```
this.dropdownRef = React.createRef();
```

Then I am triggering the dropdown with this line right before the render. This is the line that is causing the issue in my unit test.

```
this.dropdownRef.current.alertWithType('error', 'Error', this.props.firebaseInfo.errorMessage);
```

Then this is my unit test

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { SignUp } from '../SignUp';
import Enzyme, { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'


function createNodeMock() {

  return {
    DropdownAlert: {
      alertWithType() {

      }
    },
    current: {
      DropdownAlert: {
        alertWithType() {}
      }
    },
    alertWithType() {}
  }
}


describe('Sign up page component', () => {
  it('sign up renders correctly', () => {

    const props = {
      actions: {},
      userInfo: {},
      firebaseInfo: {},
    };

    const tree = renderer.create(<SignUp {...props}/>, {createNodeMock}).toJSON();

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

It keeps failing throwing the following error, even though I thought the function createNodeMock() would fix it like in this answer [Refs are null in Jest snapshot tests with react-test-renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852131/refs-are-null-in-jest-snapshot-tests-with-react-test-renderer) Any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be great

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertWithType' of null
```