# React-bootstrap Typeahead does not work with Jest snapshots

Tags: mocking, jestjs, react-test-renderer, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have a very simple **AsyncTypeahead** example from the API documentation :

```
    import {AsyncTypeahead} from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
    import React, {Component} from "react";

    class AsyncTest extends Component<Props, State> {
        constructor() {
            super()
            this.state = {
                isLoading:false,
                options:{}
            }
        }
        render() {
            return <AsyncTypeahead
                disabled={true}
                isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                onSearch={query => {
                    this.setState({isLoading: true});
                    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=123`)
                        .then(resp => resp.json())
                        .then(json => this.setState({
                            isLoading: false,
                            options: json.items,
                        }));
                }}
                options={this.state.options}
            />
        }
    }

export default AsyncTest;
```

Now if I want to create a Jest snapshot test of this component then I would write something like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import AsyncTest from "./AsyncTest";

describe('Async Test', () => {
    test('test', () => {
        const test= <AsyncTest/>
        expect(renderer.create(test).toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

This does not work. I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>
> ```
> at Window.getComputedStyle (A:\frontend\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:524:20)
> at copyStyles (A:\frontend\node_modules\react-bootstrap-typeahead\lib\containers\hintContainer.js:61:27)
> at HintedInput.componentDidMount (A:\frontend\node_modules\react-bootstrap-typeahead\lib\containers\hintContainer.js:113:9)
> at commitLifeCycles (A:\frontend\node_modules\react-test-renderer\cjs\react-test-renderer.development.js:10930:22)
> ```

Is this a known issue with bootstrap typeahead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refs are null in Jest snapshot tests with react-test-renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852131/refs-are-null-in-jest-snapshot-tests-with-react-test-renderer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and this was my solution. 
Culprit is the Hintcontainer of typeahead and specifically this function:

```
function copyStyles(inputNode, hintNode) {
  var inputStyle = window.getComputedStyle(inputNode);
  /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */

  hintNode.style.borderStyle = interpolateStyle(inputStyle, 'border', 'style');
  hintNode.style.borderWidth = interpolateStyle(inputStyle, 'border', 'width');
  hintNode.style.fontSize = inputStyle.fontSize;
  hintNode.style.lineHeight = inputStyle.lineHeight;
  hintNode.style.margin = interpolateStyle(inputStyle, 'margin');
  hintNode.style.padding = interpolateStyle(inputStyle, 'padding');
  /* eslint-enable no-param-reassign */
}
```

Problem with createMockNode: Styles from the inputNode are not a common object, but a 
CSSStyleDeclaration, and I did not bother to mock this completely.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration

So, using window.getComputedStyle does not work when swapped out with a common object.
Most simple solution to me, was to mock window.getComputedStyle, too. 
So, First part is to mock the getComputedStyle function which is triggering the error.

```
global.window.getComputedStyle = jest.fn(x=>({}));
```

But *createNodeMock*  is still needed to provide an empty style object for the input node.

**TLDR; Snapshots work with this snippet**

```
   global.window.getComputedStyle = jest.fn(x=>({}));
        const createNodeMock = (element) => ({
                style: {},
        });
   const options={createNodeMock};
   const tree = renderer
            .create(form,options)
            .toJSON();
```

Comment: I remember now that I tried with the createNodeMock... I actually posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234007/cannot-read-property-ownerdocument-of-undefined-while-mocking-ref another problem i had with that. Lets talk next week...

Comment: yes, i know, the other problem is solved by this approach