# Cannot read property '_ownerDocument' of undefined while mocking ref

Tags: react-test-renderer

I am using **createMockNode** from react-test-renderer and have mocked out the style to prevent undefined errors.

```
let createNodeMock = (element) => {
    if (element.type === 'input') {
        return {
            style: {"color":"red"},
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

This has prevented the "undefined" error on style, but now I get this
error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_ownerDocument' of undefined
        at unstable_runWithPriority (A:\frontend\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:12) TypeError: Cannot read property '_ownerDocument' of undefined
        at exports.matchesDontThrow (A:\frontend\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\selectors.js:8:27)
        at setPropertiesFromRule (A:\frontend\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:536:72)
        at forEach.call.rule (A:\frontend\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:552:11)
```

(BTW, I am testing **react-bootstrap-typeahead** inside my component.)

Am I correctly creating the mock object for the input?

Comment: solved by mocking the function : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199979/react-bootstrap-typeahead-does-not-work-with-jest-snapshots